# C Getopt : Wrong argument corresponding to its option

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments, getopt

I want to get options for this command:

```
my_cmd show --value true -D
```

To get that, I need to go through the options twice (due to architecture). During the second pass, it is impossible to retrieve correctly the argument corresponding to its option.
In this example, during the second pass the argument retrieved (for option `--value`) is `-D` instead of `true`.

First pass:

```
void getoptions (int argc, char **argv, globalargs_t* globalargs) {

    static const char *optstring = "vDqnd:c:f:o:h?:";

    static const struct option longopts[] = {
        { "help",         no_argument,        NULL,    'h' },
        { "Debug",        no_argument,        NULL,    'D'},
        { "verbose",    no_argument,        NULL,    'v'},
        { "quiet",        no_argument,        NULL,    'q'},
        { "noheader",    no_argument,        NULL,    0},
        { "delimiter",    required_argument,     NULL,    0},
        { "columns",    required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { "filter",        required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { "order",        required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { "getid",        no_argument,        NULL,    'i'},
        { NULL,            no_argument,        NULL,    0 }
    };

    int opt = 0;
    int longindex = 0;
    //opterr = 0;

    /* Process the arguments with getopt_long(), then populate globalargs-> */
    opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optstring, longopts, &longindex );
    while( opt != -1 ) {
        switch( opt ) {
            case '?':
                break;
            case 'D':
                globalargs->debug = 1;    /* true */
                break;
            case 'v':
                globalargs->verbose++;
                break;
            case 'q':
                globalargs->quiet = 1;
                break;
            case 'i':
                globalargs->id = 1;
                break;
            case 'h':
                globalargs->help = 1;
                break;
            case 0:        /* long option without a short arg */
                if( strcmp( "Debug", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->debug = 1;
                }
                if( strcmp( "verbose", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->verbose = 1;
                }
                if( strcmp( "quiet", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->quiet = 1;
                }
                if( strcmp( "noheader", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->noheader = 1;
                }
                if( strcmp( "delimiter", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->delimiter = *optarg;
                }
                if( strcmp( "filter", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->filter = optarg;
                }
                if( strcmp( "order", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->order = optarg;
                }
                if( strcmp( "columns", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->columns = optarg;
                }
                break;
            default:
                /* You won't actually get here. */
                break;
        }
        opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optstring, longopts, &longindex );
    }
    if (optind < argc) {
        while (optind < argc) {
            globalargs->actions[globalargs->actionsindex] = argv[optind++];
            globalargs->actionsindex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Second pass :

```
void getspecificoptions(int argc, char **argv, globalargs_t* globalargs) {
    static const char *optstring = ":n:d:v:d";

    static const struct option longopts[] = {
        { "name",                required_argument,     NULL,    'n'},
        { "domain",                required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { "value",                required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { "defined_value",        required_argument,    NULL,    0},
        { NULL,                    no_argument,        NULL,    0 }
    };

    optind = 1;
    int opt = 0;
    int longindex = 0;

    /* Process the arguments with getopt_long(), then populate globalargs-> */
    opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optstring, longopts, &longindex );
    while( opt != -1 ) {
        switch( opt ) {
            case 'n':
                /* If used in update/add => must be still a filter */
                globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter,"cluster.name=");
                globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter, optarg);
                if(!globalargs->table || strcmp(globalargs->table, "cluster") == 0 ) {
                    globalargs->table = "cluster";
                }
                else {
                    clmError(&t, "dbm-command", -1, "Incompatible options.");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE_OPTIONS);
                }
                break;
            case 0:        /* long option without a short arg */
                if( strcmp( "domain", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {

                    }
                    else {
                        char* f = my_new(500*sizeof(char));
                        f = strcat(f, "cluster.dns_domain=");
                        f = strcat(f, optarg);
                        globalargs->actions[globalargs->actionsindex] = f;
                        globalargs->actionsindex++;
                    }
                    if(strcmp(globalargs->table,"") == 0 || strcmp(globalargs->table, "cluster") == 0 ) {
                        globalargs->table = "cluster";
                    }
                    else {
                        clmError(&t, "dbm-command", -1, "Incompatible options.");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE_OPTIONS);
                    }
                }
                if( strcmp( "value", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    if(strcmp(globalargs->actions[0], "show") == 0 || strcmp(globalargs->actions[0], "delete") == 0 ) {
                        globalargs->filter = realloc(globalargs->filter, strlen(globalargs->filter) + strlen(optarg) + strlen("cluster_profile.value=") + 1);
                        globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter,"cluster_profile.value=");
                        globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter, optarg);
                    }
                    else {
                        char* act = my_new(strlen(optarg) + strlen("cluster_profile.value=") + 1U);
                        act = strcat(act, "cluster_profile.value=");
                        act = strcat(act, optarg);
                        globalargs->actions[globalargs->actionsindex] = act;
                        globalargs->actionsindex++;
                    }
                    if(strcmp(globalargs->table,"") == 0 || strcmp(globalargs->table, "profile") == 0 ) {
                        globalargs->table = "profile";
                    }
                    else {
                        clmError(&t, "dbm-command", -1, "Incompatible options.");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE_OPTIONS);
                    }
                }
                if( strcmp( "defined_value", longopts[longindex].name ) == 0 ) {
                    /* If used in update/add => must be still a filter */
                    globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter,"cluster_profile.defined_value=");
                    globalargs->filter = strcat(globalargs->filter, optarg);

                    if(!globalargs->table || strcmp(globalargs->table, "profile") == 0 ) {
                        globalargs->table = "profile";
                    }
                    else {
                        clmError(&t, "dbm-command", -1, "Incompatible options.");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE_OPTIONS);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optstring, longopts, &longindex );
    }
}
```

After these passes I have `globalargs->filter="-D"`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: can you put usage function, so we can see what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

optind must be reset to 0 instead of 1.  The first time through, the qualification flags are parsed, but the second time they are not, because optind is 1 and not 0.  Setting it to 0 reparses the string.

The first character of the optstring must also be + or - (before the leading colon) to prevent the arguments from being reordered.

This is all under the assumption that you are using GNU's getopt_long.

Comment: It works with a '-' in my first optstring and an optind reseted with 0. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`getopt` reorders arguments and will return all option arguments before all non-option arguments, as described in the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long):

> By default, getopt() **permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so
>   that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end**. Two other modes are
>   also implemented. If the first character of optstring is '+' or the
>   environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, then option processing
>   stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered. If the first
>   character of optstring is '-', then each nonoption argv-element is
>   handled as if it were the argument of an option with character code 1.
>   (This is used by programs that were written to expect options and
>   other argv-elements in any order and that care about the ordering of
>   the two.) The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning
>   regardless of the scanning mode.

Since the proper long syntax for `--value true` is `--value=true`, `true` gets treated as a non-option argument and shifted behind the option arguments.

Comment: In Posix, if the argument is required, then --value true is also acceptable.